# SQL Server : how to improve performance

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Our biggest table has around 7 Mio records. When I query the table on a non clustered index of type int:

Eg:

```
Select * from MyTable where TypeID = 401
```

-- it takes around 7 secs to show less than 147000 rows.

```
Select * from MyTable where TypeID like '%401%'
```

-- it takes around 13 secs to show less than 147000 rows.

Is there a way to increase performance here? Eg. more memory? We have 16GB currently.

My Table script:

```
create table MyTable (ID int not null, Description nvarchar(50) not null, TypeID int not null, primary key (ID));

create index MyTable_TypeID on MyTable (TypeID);
```

EDIT:
Most of the answer revolves around the second query which actually could be ignored. The first query should be focused instead. Is there anything that can be done to retrieve the data faster?

Comment: What means _"show less than 147000 rows"_, show where? How long does this take: `Select COUNT(*) from MyTable where TypeID = 401` ?

Comment: Well, you are using `SELECT *`, so even if it would take 0.0001 seconds to find your rows (we can know that when you answer Tim's question), it still needs to go to the table and retrieve all the data from it

Comment: What is the data type of `TypeID`? Why are you using queries that imply it's numeric and a string at the same time? Is there an index on this column? If so, does it include all of the other columns in the table? If not, have you considered using just the columns that are covered by the index (and/or changing the index) instead of using `SELECT *`?

Comment: @Tim The time which is shown lower right in the SQL Management Studio. The count is much faster, like 1 sec. But again is there a way to increase performance in this case retrieving with the data?

-@Aaron As stated above it's of type int. I'm just showing a possible query where the user doesn't know exactly the TypeID.

Comment: Yikes, you should read up on implicit conversions. If people to enter freetext to find partial matches for strings that are actually integers, you may want to consider presenting them with a drop-down of the possible values instead.

Comment: Did You try an index with included columns so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could include columns into the index (on the leaf nodes, not in the actual index) that should safe some time as after finding the right match in the leaf node no pointing to and lookup of data is required.

The bottleneck for performance is the match check that has to be done with every row, wether the check turns out positive or not. Even if your query returns no rows as a result, because no match was found, it will still need the same magnitude of time. If the resultset is large and that large amount of data must then be transported over the net that of course has negative influence as well.

EDIT: sorry for claiming result set size was irrelevant

For each matching ID the desired fields must be read out. If they are not included with the index they must be retrieved from the "normal" table by use of a pointer (address) that lies with the leaf element of the index. Including these fields makes the data available right away within the index.

Here is how to create an index with included columns

```
CREATE INDEX MyTable_TypeID on MyTable (TypeID)
INCLUDE (ID, Description, TypeID);
```

as in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189607%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Please take note that on insert or update operations such an index requires more maintenance. a gain here is a loss there.

Comment: I disagree 100% that the size of the result set is not relevant.

Comment: So, let me see if I get this right, if SQL Server uses an index seek (well, a range scan) to find 1000 rows, and I've used SELECT *, it doesn't matter if I have one integer column or 10 nvarchar(max) and XML columns, all of that data will get transmitted over the network and rendered on the client in the same amount of time?

Comment: sorry about that, of course it is not irrelevant. I tried to lay focus on queries and indexes. But machine, network and clients are of course also part of the process chain.

Answer (score 0):

Test in query optimizer
Like changes a seek to a scan
Even with no wild cards
Don't use a like if if you need =

```
Select * from MyTable where TypeID = 401
-- index seek

Select * from MyTable where TypeID like 401
-- index scan 

Select * from MyTable where TypeID like '%401%'
-- index scan
```

Why would you search on an integer like that?

If the column is char then
like 'value'  will still be an index seek
like 'value%' will still be an index seek
like '%value' will still be an index scan

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from MyTable where TypeID like '%401%'
```

This query can't use indexes so it must look through the whole table, that is why it is slower. You should never use a wildcard as the first character in a where condition if it can be in any way avoided. It shoud be avoidable with a better design especially since this is an integer field.

Comment: I tested on real data and I got an index scan with like.

Comment: @Blam But you didn't use wildcards, that's what make the query unable to use an index there

Comment: @Lamak Yes I tested on real data WITH wild cards and I got an index scan

Comment: It is possible to get an index scan in the execution plan.  For example, if you have a wide table and an index on the TypeId column, SQL Server will use the index to locate the rows because the data in the index is smaller than the data in the whole table and therefore will be faster. Note that you got an index scan.  In this case, and index scan is likely faster that a table scan or clustered index scan. The import part to realize is that you are still scanning all the rows in the index.  If you remove the leading wildcard, you will get an index seek which is orders of magnitude faster.